# SQL Bulk update all Wordpress user's nicknames to firstname + lastname format

Tags: users, sql

I'm trying to bulk update all my users on one of my Wordpress sites to so that their nicknames aren't the default username but have the format firstname + lastname instead.

I've put together this code and have run it in PhpMyAdmin but it doesn't seem to have changed anything (although I get no errors):

```
UPDATE wp_users SET user_nicename = CONCAT(
    (
        SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta 
            WHERE meta_key = 'first_name' AND user_id = ID
    ),
    ' ', 
    (
        SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta 
            WHERE meta_key = 'last_name' AND user_id = ID
    )
);
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong with this?

Comment: "doesn't seem to have changed" - does it change or not? You should be able to see and test this from PHPMyAdmin

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, in PhpMyAdmin the column has been updated but in the Wordpress user profile it's still the same as before and doesn't appear to have changed.

Answer (score 1):

You are updating the wrong column. `user_nicename` is used for the permalink of authors (so you really should undo your change if already done so in the actual database). If you want to change how usernames are displayed, update `display_name` instead.

```
UPDATE wp_users 
SET display_name = CONCAT(
    (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'first_name' AND user_id = ID),
    ' ',
    (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'last_name' AND user_id = ID)
);
```

I'm unsure if `first_name` and `last_name` can ever be `NULL`. If so, this query will fail. A more robust version would be

```
UPDATE wp_users 
SET display_name = CONCAT(
    COALESCE((SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'first_name' AND user_id = ID), ''),
    ' ',
    COALESCE((SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'last_name' AND user_id = ID), '')
);
```

Using `COALESCE(col, '')` will avoid any problems with `NULL` columns.

Comment: That's great thanks, works a treat. I though the display name was just associated with the dropdown on the user profile and was separate to the actual nickname which is why I opted for the nicename column.